# Filter output from cmd-command without having to use an intermediate file

Tags: powershell, filter, output

In this example I am filtering output from *whoami.exe* by using an intermediate .CSV-file. Is there a way I can achieve this with no use of a temporary file written to disc?

```
FUNCTION Get-MyADGroups()  {
    Push-Location
    CD $PSHOME  #I must be sure to have writing rights
    whoami /groups /fo csv   > result.csv
    $cc = Import-Csv -Path .\result.csv
    $cc | select -ExpandProperty 'GROUP NAME'
   rm result.csv
   Pop-Location
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet:

```
function Get-MyADGroups  
{
    whoami /groups /fo csv | 
        ConvertFrom-Csv | 
        select -ExpandProperty 'Group Name'
}
```

Comment: What If I want to see only BUILDIN? Is there a way to filter output?